# Let $T: V \rightarrow W $ be a linear mapping such that $T^2=T$, show that $V = M \oplus N$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V $ be a linear mapping such that $T^2=T$. If $M = Image(T)$ and N = $Ker(T)$,

I want to show that $V = M \oplus N$. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What is the kernel of N? N is a subspace and doesn't have a kernel. If you mean the kernel of **T**, then no: T can have a very non-trivial kernel.

Comment: @T.Bongers mistyped and edited.